# Can I execute sudo make install twice from different locations?

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

I am on Mac, Snow Lepard.

In preparation to install PIL I need to install libjpeg.
So, from my home directory I did:

```
tar zxvf jpegsrc.v6b.tar.gz
cd jpeg-6b
cp /usr/share/libtool/config/config.sub .
cp /usr/share/libtool/config/config.guess .
./configure --enable-shared --enable-static
make
sudo make install
```

But actually I read later it would have been better to this from src directory to keep all source together neatly.
Can I just do the above over from /usr/local/src or will that mess up my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question doesn't really have much to do with Python...;-).  Anyway, yes, repeating the same steps in a different directory should "overwrite" the installation you just performed.